# What is the purpose of collecting feathers?

Tags: assassins-creed-3

I am currently playing as Connor. I see feather locations a lot on my map. Some of the feathers I have collected. But what can I do with the feathers?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to [SegmentNext](http://segmentnext.com/2012/10/30/assassins-creed-3-feathers-locations-guide-how-to-find/) and [GameFAQs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps3/621796-assassins-creed-iii/cheats), collecting all the Feathers will unlock the Kanien’keha:ka outfit in your manor.

As well, you earn bragging rights and progress towards 100% completion of the game.

Comment: In my experience so far they're all fairly trivial to reach as long as you can find the right tree to climb.

Comment: I haven't played AC III as I'm waiting for the PC release. but from my experience from previous AC games, the enjoyment of the game is also from exploring the environment and the feeling of accomplishment when an extremely tall and hard building was climbed. So all the different collectables are just "excuses" provided by the designers for the player to explore and climb the environment. If you find it tedious, you can skip it and your experience and gameplay shouldn't suffer.

Answer (score -4):

When u collect all the feathers the native outfit becomes unlocked,  at first it seems like this outfit is useless but i noticed connor was much faster and agile while free running while he had this outfit on

Comment: Please do not copy another answer, and do you think you can clarify; have a credible source for the `i noticed connor was much faster and agile while free running while he had this outfit on` bit?

Comment: This answer adds nothing that isn't said by the accepted answer.